# touchswipe swipe along with click function on the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

is it possible to utilize touchswipe on an element that already has a click function?

```
$('#myelem').click(function() {
 // do stuff
});
```

I tried using:

```
$('#myelem').on ('click swipe', function() {
// do stuff
});
```

..but I don't know how to load touchswipe's options then. :/

Also, is it possible to have touchswipe on an image element?

I would be greatful for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem but only on android devices. I managed to get it working with TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin and the following code:

```
$('#myelem').swipe( {

    click:function(event,target){
        myFunction();
    },                                          
    swipeLeft: function() {
        myFunction();
    },
    swipeRight: function() {
        // do something on right swipe
    },
    allowPageScroll: 'vertical'
});

function myFunction() {
    // do something
};
```

[more info](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues/70)

Comment: What I would like is to avoid having the same function twice. Meaning, I want in both click and swipeLeft have the exact same function

Comment: Just call the same function on the the swipe event and the click event. I'll edit my answer to give an example

Comment: ..actually I just realized that touchswipe is incompatible with IE, and this is of great importance to me. However, I will give you the right answer as soon as you reply

Comment: what solution have you found?

Comment: I ended up using hammer.js I am testing just now, but it works in IE and it's syntax is a lot easier: element.hammer().on("click swipeleft", function(event) { (..)

Comment: ok, for my project I'm using modernizr to detect browser features. I used if(!$('.no-touch').length) {} to target touch screen devices and I just assumed mobile versions of IE wouldn't have a problem. I didn't take into account older versions of IE being used with touch screen devices

Comment: ...the lowest version of ie used in cellphones, as far as I know is ie9, but touchswipe still not working on desktop ie9, so that is a major issue. Anyway, thanks for your time!